# Repeated question meme - how can I get more money in my job/negotiation?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Every day, I'm seeing a repeated meme, and I'm wondering if we we are getting to a subset where we want to try to have some sort of meta-answer or meta-question/answer set that we could start referencing for duplicates.

I see two general meta-questions that could each have their own answer thread:

1 - what is the right strategy for getting more money in a new job negotation?

2 - what is the right strategy for getting more money in my current situation?

I'm starting to see enough permutations of this general concept that it's starting to feel rather repetitive.  We are working edge cases, to be sure, but I feel like we're going to narrow down on the same two answers in most cases.

Here's some examples of the questions I mean:

Case 1 - more money during job negotiation:

[Is suggesting a monthly or yearly increase in salary better?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3921/is-suggesting-a-monthly-or-yearly-increase-in-salary-better)

[How can I determine a reasonable salary to ask for?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-can-i-determine-a-reasonable-salary-to-ask-for)

[Is it OK to ask for a higher salary than what you listed as your expected salary?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3931/is-it-ok-to-ask-for-a-higher-salary-than-what-you-listed-as-your-expected-salary)

[Can I refuse to reveal the salary for my last position if it was a bit low?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1941/can-i-refuse-to-reveal-the-salary-for-my-last-position-if-it-was-a-bit-low)

[What is a successful salary negotiation strategy in the presence of a big performance bonus?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1424/what-is-a-successful-salary-negotiation-strategy-in-the-presence-of-a-big-perfor)

[Does the first person to mention a number in a salary negotiation lose?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/183/does-the-first-person-to-mention-a-number-in-a-salary-negotiation-lose)

[What are some common salary negotiation tactics from the employer's perspective?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/what-are-some-common-salary-negotiation-tactics-from-the-employers-perspective)

[How to negotiate a job offer effectively during and after an interview](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2652/how-to-negotiate-a-job-offer-effectively-during-and-after-an-interview)

Case 2 - more money at existing job:

[Manager's salary too low to ask for raise](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3887/managers-salary-too-low-to-ask-for-raise)

[How do I renegotiate my salary when new hires start in higher ranges?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/how-do-i-renegotiate-my-salary-when-new-hires-start-in-higher-ranges)

[When should I ask for more money in conjunction with more responsibility?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/625/when-should-i-ask-for-more-money-in-conjunction-with-more-responsibility)

I stopped short after a while.  There's many other salary-related questions that DON'T fall into this pile - I tried to skip anything that wasn't tightly tied to the negotation process.

But I'm starting to feel like we've answered the general things about valuation, negotiation, and how to bring up the conversation.  Most of what I see churning up lately has been people findng edge cases that often boil down to the general answer plus "It depends" relating to the unique case.

Comment: I would consider new tag called like salary-negotiation and filling respective [tag wiki as recommended at MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/tag-wiki/info)

Comment: @Jim In fact, this very post can be a good start, if properly tagged and maintained to include the most outstanding Q&A.

Comment: Hi @Jim, The problem with community wiki is that it encourages list/polls, which aren't really that useful. It's best to have a series of more targeted questions with targeted answers that someone from Google won't have to sort through just to find something helpful for them. See [The Future of Community Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) for more details. Also, closing as duplicates is another great solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you start to see a lot of repetitive questions, one possible approach to take would be sorting through the current list and finding examples that could be considered exact duplicates. *It looks like you already have a great start.*

One of the close reasons is in fact "exact duplicate":

> **exact duplicate**
>   This question covers exactly the same content as earlier questions on this topic; its answers may be merged with another identical question.

In the blog post [Handling Duplicate Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/), Jeff Atwood describes 3 different types of duplicates:

- Cut-and-paste duplicate questions
- Accidental duplicates
- Borderline duplicates

**Cut and Paste:**

Only the first type, cut and paste duplicates, should be downvoted just for being duplicates, as those have no value. People who post these have no clue how our site works, and just create more work for the community.

**Accidental Duplicates:**

The second type, accidental duplicates, shouldn't be downvoted just for being a duplicate, but could be downvoted for other reasons, like being low quality. The accidental duplicates could be voted to close as duplicates, if it's clear the questions are the same and will have the same answers as another linked post. These could be upvoted if they're valuable. Remember, duplicates help increase the chances that someone from Google may find our site, and a series of closed duplicates could link these visitors to a canonical post.

**Borderline Duplicates:**

The third type, borderline duplicates, are just that, borderline. It may be worth posting a link as a comment suggesting the answers there may be helpful, but if the post is different enough to where answers could be different, it may be worth leaving it open.

See the [Handling Duplicate Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/) blog post for a more in-depth, official explanation of how to handle duplicates.